# c++ curl returns receive error when usng proxies

Tags: c++, c, curl, proxy

As the header says, I am trying to load a page with proxy using curl on c++.
I have tried the proxy with curl linux command and got a result without a password, on my code i do:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, curlRead);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, agent);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_IGNORE_CONTENT_LENGTH, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "<proxy IP>:80");

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

but res returns as 56 (CURLE_RECV_ERROR) and the manual says

> Failure with receiving network data.

EDIT: I have tried another proxy (also working from terminal) and now I dont get a response at all, it simply stuck.

Comment: Look at the network traffic with a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark. You are probably just misconfiguring libcurl. The curl command-line app uses the libcurl library, so anything you can do with the app, you can do in your code. The app's source code is publically available, go look at it and see what options it is setting that are different than what your code is setting.